# Jetpack Compose with Coroutine's StateFlow

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am running into a strange issue while using StateFlow with Jetpack Compose, where I am not receiving the updated value in the StateFlow. This is the code how I try to observe the Stateflow as suggested in the examples.

```
@Composable
fun List(homeViewModel: HomeViewModel) {

val appState by homeViewModel.stateFlow.collectAsState()

if (appState.isLoading) {
    CircularProgressIndicator()
}
MaterialTheme {
    LazyColumn {
        items(appState.names) { name ->
            Name(name = name.name)
        }
    }
}
```

}

I receive the initial value correctly but not the updated value

```
setContent {
  Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                List(mainViewModel.homeViewModel)
      }
}
```

I have defined my stateFlow in the viewModel like this

```
internal val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(AppState())
```

I update the value by this

```
stateFlow.value = AppState(loading = false, listOf("1", "2"))
```

my AppState Pojo

```
data class AppState(val names: List<Names> = emptyList(), val isLoading: Boolean = true, val error: Throwable? = null)
```

The problem is when I update the value of stateFlow like above I expect the composable to recompose and update the value but the updated value never comes to my composable method above. I need a little help on where I am going wrong

> PS: I haven't tried this on LiveData yet

Comment: What does your `AppState` class look like?
See https://handstandsam.com/2021/01/15/my-mutablestateflow-didnt-emit/

Comment: AppState is just a pojo model data class with all 3 properties declared as val. I have updated the question with appstate class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going on basis of https://github.com/cyph3rcod3r/D-KMP-Architecture project you mentioned on twitter:

Issue is that in following code a new instance of `HomeViewModel` is being created each time getter is called meaning that `homeViewModel.stateFlow` that you're observing and instance that you're updating are different.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
     val homeViewModel get() = HomeViewModel()

    fun getListOfNames(){
        homeViewModel.getList()
    }
}
```

Comment: -_- So silly of me to miss out this. Thanks a lot @john for pointing this out, removing get() from variable worked fine. Thanks for the community support 